# Help identify this 70s or 80s lego space set

Tags: set-identification, space

I bought some bags of LEGO bricks which appear to contain a 1970's space set in it. I want to find instructions to put it all back together.

[image: Pieces of space set]

Answer (score 4):

The brick with the space logo is from either [set 452/894](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=452-1) or [set 6901](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=6901-1).  The buggy is technic [set 1972](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=1972-1).  Information from Bricklink search.